# How do you pronounce the word Shaman?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, ipa

I found 2 American pronunciation samples on Forvo, and they said /ˈʃæmən/ ([audio](https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/?w=/%CB%88%CA%83%C3%A6m%C9%99n/))), I wonder if British people say /ˈʃeɪmən/ ([audio](https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/?w=/%CB%88%CA%83e%C9%AAm%C9%99n/)), or not? Could you please tell me something about that?

Comment: The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177388?redirectedFrom=shaman#eid) clearly has a lot to say pronunciation-wise.  {Brit. /ˈʃɑːmən/, /ˈʃamən/, /ˈʃeɪmən/,  U.S. /ˈʃɑmən/, /ˈʃeɪmən/}

Answer (score 1):

As an American I consistently say /ˈʃæmən/ and don't recall ever hearing anyone, American or otherwise, saying /ˈʃeɪmən/.

The latter might be a regional difference? I've lived in a half dozen or so different places and haven't come across it.  Still, I haven't covered them all.

Per Peter Shor's comment /ˈʃeɪmən/ is the primary pronunciation in at least one [dictionary of British English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/shaman).

***Note**: Since I relied on personal experience as a native speaker for this answer I'll mention that my formative speaking years were spent in the Northeastern United States and that I have spent significant time living in the South Atlantic, Midwest, and Mountain regions of my country.  I consume media mostly in American and British English.*

Comment: /ˈʃeɪmən/ is pretty common, making it sound like it starts with the *shame* at the front. /ˈʃæmən/ would start like the word *sham*.

Comment: Is it common in the U.S. @tchrist or do you mean common in the Anglosphere? Where do you run into it?  Maybe there's an audio or video example to link to online.

Comment: /ˈʃeɪmən/ is given as the main pronunciation in the (British) [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/shaman). I can only find it as an alternate pronunciation in [American](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shaman) [dictionaries](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shaman). I suspect that in the U.S. it is a regional pronunciation, and that it's more common in the U.K.

Comment: I have only ever heard "shawmen" (First syllable like ’bother’)

Comment: @PeterShor  The CED appears to have it wrong with the US IPA.  They transcribe it as /ʃeɪmən/, but if you listen to it, it clearly says /ʃ'ɑːmən/.

Comment: @Lordology: The CED is based in England, and occasionally gets American pronunciation wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor OK.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I hear both "SHAME-an" and "SHAW-man" here in the U.S. I just listened to a 2009 lecture on shamanism by a U.S. expert on the subject, Dr. Stanley Krippner (in order to copy-edit a transcript) and in that lecture, a keynote talk for the International Association for the Study of Dreams, he consistently says "shaman" like "SHAME-an," and "shamanism" like "SHAW-man-ism." But I'm trying to find a link to a Krippner talk that's available to the general public, and so far I'm only finding him saying "SHAW-man" -- so Google him yourself, and see what you can find!